# Configuring content process sandbox level in Thunderbird

Tags: linux, firefox, thunderbird, sandbox, about-config

I am using Thunderbird 115.6.0 on Linux (Debian 12). In the menubar, clicking on "Help" > "Troubleshooting Information" shows Thunderbird's sandbox settings:

[image: Thunderbird sandbox settings]

Notice that the value of "Content Process Sandbox Level" (`security.sandbox.content.level`) and "Effective Content Process Sandbox Level" are both `0`. What does a value of `0` indicate?

The value of `security.sandbox.content.level` in Mozilla Thunderbird 115.6.0 is `0` whereas it is `4` in Mozilla Firefox 115.6.0esr. Should I set `security.sandbox.content.level` to `4` in Thunderbird too?

Comment: A value of zero is useful only for debugging purposes. It allows a content process to output its logging to a file.